# rep function in R function

Tags: r

I understand why the `rep` function didn't work out by trial and error, and that in order for the `random.sum(5)` to work out, `rep(100, 10)` has to be `rep(100, 5)`. but i do not understand why:

```
# clear the workspace
rm(list=ls())

random.sum <- function(n) {
  x[1:n] <- ceiling(10*runif(n))
  cat("x:", x[1:n] ,"\n")
  return(sum(x))
}

set.seed(3585)

x <- rep(100,10)

show(random.sum(10))
x: 9 4 10 1 9 8 4 1 3 2 
## [1] 51

show(random.sum(5))
x: 9 6 6 2 2 
## [1] 525
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Practically speaking, it's wise to avoid side effects (i.e. trying to modify `x` outside the `random.sum` function). You don't need to declare `x` in the global environment to use it within in `random.sum`.

Comment: this was a question given in my assignment to find out whats wrong with the function. i could see what was wrong in the function but couldnt determine what was wrong, so i took a trial an error and found that it was the rep (100,10) that was causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are not creating a new variable `x` in  your function, but taking a copy of the `x` in the enclosing environment, and modifying that.  So `sum(x)` adds 10 elements, the final five of which have the value `100`.

To fix, don't assign to a slice of `x`, assign the result of `ceiling` to a variable, of any name, even `x`:

```
random.sum <- function(n) {
  x <- ceiling(10*runif(n))
  cat("x:", x[1:n] ,"\n")
  return(sum(x))
}

set.seed(3585)
random.sum(10)
## x: 9 4 10 1 9 8 4 1 3 2 
## [1] 51

random.sum(5)
## x: 9 6 6 2 2 
## [1] 25
```

Note the difference is 500, the final elements of the global `x`.